# What's the song that plays in season 4 episode 14 of Boku no Hero Academia at 10:10?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In season 4 episode 14 of *Boku no Hero Academia* at 10:10, there's a song playing on the scene where the league of villains tries to get their hands on overhaul while he's being transported to a hospital.

What is the title of this song?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-LfFUJpbnA
Vanguard Action Squad All-out Attack OST